# Downloaded Cinnamon Interface on Ubuntu 18. Is Bluetooth connection normal?

Tags: bluetooth, cinnamon

this may seem like a silly question, but I realised that when I changed the panel settings there was a Bluetooth icon on the bottom dock. Is bluetooth needed for anything important? I don't have any bluetooth connections on anything and thought whether there were any possible security vulnerabilities having it on.

Is Bluetooth required to be on for any important Ubuntu software or apps? Bionic Beaver or anything? If I kept it on nothing external outside of my laptop would connect to it automatically, right? I just found it odd that it was there. I had a bad case where my previous laptop was hacked into through my mobile wifi so sorry if I sound slightly paranoid. Should I be concerned or is it totally okay? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can hide it from the panel with no consequence.

Security vulnerabilities, if any, will be addressed in updates.

Comment: Thanks @K7AAY. I figured this was the case!